# How to filter django x chart.js charts? Uncaught TypeError

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-rest-framework, chart.js

Hello im attempting to filter chart.js charts. The way im inputting the data from my database is via the django rest framework API. Here is what i have done:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
endpoint = 'api/chart/data'
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: endpoint,    
  success: function(data){
    sales_time = data.sales_time_axis
    sales_rev = data.sales_rev
    conversion_label = data.conversion_label
    conversion_data= data.conversion_data
    profit_data_per_project= data.profit_data_per_project


    var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');

    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels:sales_time,
        datasets: [{
            label: sales_time,
            data: profit_data_per_project,
            backgroundColor: [
                    'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
                ],
                borderColor: [
                    'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                    'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                    'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                    'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
                ],
                borderWidth: 1
            }]
        },
        options: {
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero: true
                    }   
                }]
            }
        }
  });
 },
error: function(error_data){
console.log('error')
console.log(error_data)
}
})
```

This is my template:

```
       <div class="card-body" id="card_body">
      <select class="text_select" id="chart-select" onchange="applyFilter(value, myChart)" name="select">
        <option value="All">All Time</option>
        <option value="3">Last 3 Months</option>
        <option value="6">Last 6 Months</option>
        <option value="12">Last Year</option>
        <option value="24">Last 2 Years</option>
      </select>
      <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
    </div>
```

this is the javascript call that im using to test my code:

```
function applyFilter(value, chart){
if (value == '3'){
    console.log(sales_time);
    sales_time.splice(-1,1);
    console.log(sales_time);
    } ;
chart.update()
}
```

However , im getting this error when i select '3 Months' in my console:

```
 (2) [Array(1), Array(1)]
(index):326 [Array(1)]
(index):328 Uncaught TypeError: chart.update is not a function
    at applyFilter ((index):328)
    at HTMLSelectElement.onchange ((index):105)
applyFilter @ (index):328
onchange @ (index):105
```

As such i have two questions , is there a better way to get the results i want? Why am i getting the error?

Your help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `myChart` is being defined in a callback function for the ajax request. Define it outside any function definition so that you can pass around references to it

Comment: @IainShelvington Hello sir , sorry im new to this , how would you go about defining it outside the ajax function and still be able to pass values into it?

Comment: Yes, you can simply pass the variables that you have declared to the function you define for creating charts. That will make your code cleaner too!